# I edited gitignore to allow my images storage folder to upload, but when I push nothing is updated

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I recently setup post-receive hooks on my digital ocean droplet and connected it with my laravel local project. Everything works great except my public/storage/images don't get uploaded with each commit. I tried to edit my local .gitignore file so it doesnt include the public/storage folder but nothing is being uploaded when I commit. Here is my current .gitignore file contents

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/storage/framework/*.key
/storage/logs/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vscode
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
```

I changed the /public/storage and /storage/*.key

Thanks Chris

Comment: I think you can just do `!public/storage/images/*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but nothing is being uploaded when I commit.

Check if another rule is ignoring your folder:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/a/file/to/add
```

If the folder or any parent folder is ignored, you should whitelist it, then whitelist the content:

```
!public/
!public/storage/
!public/storage/images/
!public/storage/images/*
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question but when I try to do the git check-ignore it keeps telling me that no such folder or file exists. I did try adding the whitelist and commiting and pushing to the server but still no images.

Comment: @ChrisGrim make sure you are in the Git repo and are using a relative path to an existing file.